# Finding but not removing duplicates in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, duplicates, cell

I have a big array in Matlab like this:

A =

```
{1x5  cell}
{1x7  cell}
{1x27 cell}
{1x11 cell}
  ...
```

where the cells look like this:

> > C{1}

ans = 
'apple' 'banana' 'kiwi' 'orange'

I want to find where in A find cells containing double information, like:

> > C{27}

ans = 
'turtle' 'kiwi' 'fox' 'badger'

I.e. here I want to see if C(1) and C(27) has a duplicate word 'kiwi'. 
So I can manually look at them and decide where I should remove the duplicate where I see fit.

Comment: my first question on Stack so please tell me if I need to make anything more clear. 

Thanks!

Comment: People tend to be more ameniable to questions along the lines of "here's what I've tried but I'm stuck on this bit" style of questions rather than this is what I want to do. Hence the style of my response - I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm not going to provide a coded solution, more the process I'd use so that you can start coding, if you then have any specific problems fell free to post an question

I would use `nchoosek` to generate an array of all the permutations of the cell array `C` so

```
nCells = length(C);
nPerms = nchoosek(1:nCells,2);
```

You can then loop over all the permutations using intersect to see if there are common strings.

```
result(i) = intersect(C{nPerms(i,1)},C{nPerms(i,2)});
```

This will give you an array listing all common strings and with the nPerms array you'll have the two rows with the common string. However if you try to run this it will fail as `intersect` likes to have the same number of element in each cell array.

So I'd create a temporary cell array padded out with blank cells so that each element in C is the same length, prior to the loop.

This will calculate the longest cell in the array C by calculating the number of elements (@numel) in each cell, followed by calculating the maximum.

```
cSize = cellfun(@numel,C);
maxSize = max(cSize);
```

We can then define a function to pad out blank cells

```
fcn = @(x) [x cell(1,maxSize - numel(x))];
paddedC = cellfun(fcn,C,'UniformOutput',false);
```

This should give you a cell array with same number of elements in each cell. You can then use this cell array in your loop testing each permutation.

No doubt someone will turn up with a one line cellfun solution but I hope that this is enough to get you started.